# How to inject named logger into constructor using GUICE

Tags: java, logging, guice, slf4j

I know how to create custom injections/annotations from [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) and [here](http://forkbomb-blog.de/2012/slf4j-logger-injection-with-guice). the problem with this is, the logger is not usable within constructor (fields got injected after construction). On the other hand this

```
@Provides Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) { 
    return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName()); 
}
```

is not working with guice.
So is there a way to get named logger (**slf4j** in my case) injected into constructor with guice?

Comment: What's the reason for injecting the logger? It's customary for loggers specifically to get put in a `private static final` field.

Comment: i am too lazy to always type LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThisClassName.class); for same reason there are these 2 links i gave (i am not the only one who is lazy)

Comment: Then be even lazier and use Groovy. It'll do it for you.

Comment: This is possible in Guice 4, but not at all in Guice 3.  My implementation is here: https://github.com/tavianator/sangria/blob/master/sangria-slf4j/src/main/java/com/tavianator/sangria/slf4j/SangriaSlf4jModule.java

Comment: Thanks for info - please add this as answer and please add a link to "Slf4jLoggerProvider.class" - thanks